# Need help on unix time stamp

Tags: timestamp, unix-timestamp

Basically, am creating a mailer system to send a mail to my inactive members to do activities in their account if they have not logged in since 30 days.

My previous login date stores in my database in unixtimestamp hence I coded as below.

```
  select email from myusers where WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(prelogin), INTERVAL 30 DAY) < CURDATE()";
```

But this code after 30 days it is sending continuos mails almost everyday as I have set cron to run once a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want an email sent every 30 days, and only if they haven't logged in for 30 days, I suspect the easiest solution will be to have *another* column in your table called something like `last_email_sent_time`.

Then, only send an email if it's been at least 30 days since both `prelogin` *and* that new column.

And, when you send the email, update that new column to the current date so you won't bother them for another month or so.

---

On the other hand, if you just want the email sent *once* after they haven't logged in for thirty days, it's a similar thing.

Create a new column indicating the email has been sent and only send it if that column is false (or `N` or whatever you want to use to indicate it). Sending it will set that column to true, logging in will set it to false (as well as changing `prelogin`).

---

If you *don't* want to add extra columns (for some bizarre reason), you could simply update `prelogin` when you send the email, though that's not something I'm comfortable suggesting since it loses information that may be used (or useful) elsewhere.

Comment: thats a nice trick which i did not think of but is it not possible with right query?

Comment: @sammry, it depends. If you just want to do it 30 days after last login, you can change it from `WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(prelogin), INTERVAL 30 DAY) < CURDATE()` to `WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(prelogin), INTERVAL 30 DAY) = CURDATE()` - that'll do it once and once only unless they log in again at some point. But, if you don't have that simplest of requirements, then you'll need to store the fact _somewhere_ that an email has been sent.

Comment: i tried with = but did not work then only i posted on this forum

Comment: You might find that it's because you're working with timestamps rather than just dates, in which case the cronjob may need to run at exactly the same time down to the nearest subsecond :-) You could try forcing the timestamp to a date, but I'd just introduce the extra column myself.