# Updating a field after sending a mail

Tags: php, mysql

I have a reminder mail sent to those who do not log on to my site after 30 days.  Earlier I got an answer on this forum to create a seperate field and then update it as mentioned here: [Need help on unix time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384550/need-help-on-unix-time-stamp).

I have created a new field `lastprelogin`, now how do I update the respective field when I send the mail for inactive users.

```
<?php
include("include/data.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM myusers WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(lastprelogin), INTERVAL 15 DAY) < CURDATE()";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num)
{
    //send mail code
    $sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
    $i++;
    if($sendmail) {
        $query1 = "UPDATE myusers SET lastprelogin='".time()."'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query1);
    }
}
?>
```

How can I update the respective user's `lastprelogin` field after sending the mail?

I am lost here beccause am unable to understand the logic in this part.

Comment: Why are you updating *all* users on every run through the loop?

Comment: I have put that to get answer, am not updating as of now

Comment: Wait, so you've put something in your sample that you're not actually doing? I'm not sure how we can guess that. Put the code that's failing, not what you think is wrong.

Comment: You can add new field `active` to your table `myusers` and set it to "0".
After sending the e-mail set it to "1" with respect to `user_id`.

Comment: @alkhader I wouldn't recommend adding confusing semantics to it. Sending them an email saying "come back" does not make them "active".

Comment: @Cylindric, I want to use the where clause in query1 so that i update the respective user only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of Your script is simple:

- retrieve all the users that didn't log in for last 15 days
- send an email to each user
- and if that succeeds also update the field lastprelogin for that user

You have some important errors within Your script and this should be like this:

```
include("include/data.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM myusers WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(lastprelogin), INTERVAL 15 DAY) < CURDATE()";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // assuming that myusers table has these columns: user_id, user_name, user_email, lastprelogin
    //send mail code
    if(mail($user['user_email'],'Please log in','Please login to my site',$headers)) {
        $query1 = "update myusers set lastprelogin='".time()."' where user_id = {$user['usri_id']}";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query1);
    }
}
// end.
```

As a `$headers` variable You can set a `From` header, etc. Look for PHP mail function here: http://php.net/mail

Also the right query for updating should be this one:

```
"update myusers set lastprelogin='".time()."' where user_id = {$user['user_id']}"
```

anyway You will update the `lastprelogin` of all users everytime...

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop through your results by using [mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or similar function.

Your update query needs to include the ID of the record you wish to update.

You should *not* use the `mysql_*` functions anymore as they are becoming deprecated soon. Use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead

```
<?php
    include("include/data.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM myusers WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(lastprelogin), INTERVAL 15 DAY) < CURDATE()";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    
    while ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        //send mail code
        $sendmail = mail($user['email_address'],$subject,$msg,$headers);
        $i++;
        if($sendmail){
            $query1 = "update myusers set lastprelogin='".time()."' WHERE id = " . $user['id'];
            $result2 = mysql_query($query1);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: will try this and let you know here

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get some `id` from your `myuser` table and run the `update` query with `where id = $id`.

Comment: I do get id something like     $id = mysql_result($result,$i,"UID"); but will taht work?

Comment: It sounds like it should work, but without knowing the exact code and database structure, I can't be sure. I'd say: try it. Maybe on some backup environment where it's safe to try it on in case it goes wrong...